# Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http): missing required field "paths"

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod

I am very new to using helm charts and not sure why I get this error when I try to install my helm chart. I am using --set with helm install command to set the hostname at ingress.hosts[0].host.I do not understand why it says missing paths where as "paths" is already present.

ingress.yaml

```
{{- if .Values.ingress.enabled -}}
{{- $fullName := include "project.fullname" . -}}
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: {{ $fullName }}
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: {{ include "project.name" . }}
    helm.sh/chart: {{ include "project.chart" . }}
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: {{ .Release.Name }}
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: {{ .Release.Service }}
  {{- with .Values.ingress.annotations }}
  annotations:
    {{- toYaml . | nindent 4 }}
  {{- end }}
spec:
{{- if .Values.ingress.tls }}
  tls:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.tls }}
    - hosts:
      {{- range .hosts }}
        - {{ . | quote }}
      {{- end }}
      secretName: {{ .secretName }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
  rules:
  {{- range .Values.ingress.hosts }}
    - host: {{ .host | quote }}
      http:
        paths:
        {{- range .paths }}
          - path: {{ . }}
            backend:
              serviceName: {{ $fullName }}
              servicePort: http
        {{- end }}
  {{- end }}
{{- end }}
```

values.yaml

```
...
...
...
ingress:
  enabled: true
  hostname: some_hostname
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    kubernetes.io/tls-acme: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-connect-timeout: "180"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-send-timeout: "180"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/proxy-read-timeout: "180"
  hosts:
    - host: some_hostname
      paths: [/]

  tls:
    - secretName: some_secretname
      hosts: 
        - some_hostname

resources: {}

...
...
...
```

command to install helm

```
helm upgrade --install $(PROJECT_NAME) --set ingress.hosts[0].host="${HOST_NAME} --set ingress.tls[0].hosts="{${HOST_NAME}}""
```

error:

```
Error: UPGRADE FAILED: error validating "": error validating data: ValidationError(Ingress.spec.rules[0].http): missing required field "paths" in io.k8s.api.extensions.v1beta1.HTTPIngressRuleValue
```

Comment: did you try doing this:  ```paths:
   - "/"``` instead ? should be just like you presented `hosts.host`, instead of `["/"]`

Comment: @SaikatChakrabortty yes I tried that as well,doesn't help.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue, for some reason if you define the host in the `--set` you also have to define the path in the set (even though it matches the yaml). Like so,

```
helm upgrade --install $(PROJECT_NAME) --set ingress.hosts[0].host=${HOST_NAME}  --set ingress.hosts[0].paths[0]=/
```

I haven't done tls yet so I am not sure if that has the same issue.

Comment: This was also the solution at my end. The [documentation](https://helm.sh/docs/intro/using_helm/) isn't very clear but it appears to override the values so you end up having to specifiy both. For the TLS I had to specify both the secret name as well as the host.